# Blazor Razor Class Library (RCL) No CSS Intellisense

Tags: c#, css, razor, intellisense

I have a razor class library (RCL) that contains all the pages from my blazor application. The **CSS intellisense** does not seem to work within the RCL unless I change the RCL .csproj xml tag **From** Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" **To** Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" .

Example: <p class="..(no intellisense is shown if used within an RCL)"

I am using VS2022 with the latest updates. Any information that can help resolve this issue, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KevinMueller.HtmlCssClassCompletion22), that tackles this exact problem.

It should solve your problem, as it scans every project that exists in the solution, not just the ones of the type `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

Furthermore, it also adds support for isolated CSS contexts (*.razor.css files), as well as external files, which are linked via the <link> attribute in an HTML file.

You can find more info about it in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/kevin-mueller/HtmlCssClassCompletion).

Comment: Wanna point out sth. I'm using Blazor with the standard/default bootstrap 5. SOMETIMES VS actually loads intellicode correctly, and displays the bootstrap.css classes. MOST TIMES however it's buggy as hell, and only suggest css classes from my isolation css files (even if the file does not even apply to the component). I find that extremely annoying, buggy and inconsistent and I don't even see a pattern. RARELY deleting bin + obj helps, but not always. This extension gives me some relieve. Hope VS gets fixes sometime!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Blazor css intellisense is not that great. So my work around was to change the .csproj to Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" reload the solution and then add a "Program.cs" class file to the root with one line of code.

It doesn't matter what that line of code does just add a line of code. In my project I added a variable like `var workAround="empty";` to the program.cs file.

Now the css intellisense magically works. It doesn't work that great but it works. Microsoft needs to fix this.

[image]

Another thing to add is to close visual studio and delete the .vs folder. This is a hidden folder where you project resides.

[image]

Comment: With this workaround did you run into any issues with a bunch of css classes not showing up in the list?  The only thing showing up in my list are classes for the font awesome library. I'm missing all of my classes as well as bootstrap.  Any idea on how the css intellisense gets built or where the css is being pulled from?

Comment: I had no issues, witht the work around I described above; it just takes a little bit of time for the css intellisense to catch up once you made the changes. Also from my understanding if you are using an RCL project make sure your css is located under the wwwroot so intellisense can pick it up. Let me know if that helps.