# How do I get CSS variable intellisense within Blazor CSS isolation files

Tags: css, visual-studio, blazor

I am currently using Visual Studio 2022 (Current Version as of this question). When I attempt to use a CSS variable within a Blazor CSS Isolation file, intellisense give me no suggestions for auto-complete. In fact, it doesn't even suggest auto-completion for Var(). I have several CSS variables located in a CSS file within my wwwroot folder and would like to have suggestions when writing CSS in the isolation files. Is there an extension or a settings tweak that I can use to get those suggestions?

Even though Intellisense doesn't give me any suggestions. If I complete the variable name within the isolation file and run, the variable is resolved and rendered correctly. The only issue is the intellisense does not seem to be aware of my variables within the wwwroot folder and therefore doesn't offer any suggestions.

Please any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor Razor Class Library (RCL) No CSS Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735285/blazor-razor-class-library-rcl-no-css-intellisense)

Comment: No, I have tried that extension already. It does work, but only adds the CSS classes when in an HTML file. My problem is the intellisense for variables while working in a CSS file (Specifically the CSS Isolation Files).

Comment: If you are not using the latest preview version of Visual Studio 2022, I would suggest upgrading to that. Otherwise, you will have to wait for Microsoft to get better support. Having said that, Visual Studio Code is great for CSS files.